# Set document.cookie after manipulations with Date

Tags: javascript, cookies, token

Please help me understand if it's a browser bug or not.
I'm developing a token based web application and would like to set token data to `document.cookie`.
It works fine, but here is one scenario when it doesn't work.
If user sets local datetime to date when token is expired, a value of this token won't be added to `document.cookie` (and this is normal behavior).

If user will return local datetime to real date (and now token is not expired), a value of this token won't be added again, what unexpactable. Howewer, it works after browser restart.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var cookieStr = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
document.cookie = cookieStr;
```

Comment: Does it work again on page refresh?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only browser restart.